# Excel VBA - message when clicking on a protected cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a protected Excel sheet and I have set it not to select protected cells.
It is possible to make a message appear when the user clicks a specific protected cell, in my case F3? (The keyboard cursors/enter/tab don't allow the user to reach this cell, only the mouse).

Comment: How do you select the cell if the sheet is protected to not select cells?  Only way I've found is to enter the cell address in the Name box and then @Marks code runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can use a small Sub in the VBA Editor under the Developer tools to display a message when the user selects a cell, in your case, F3.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$F$3" Then
    MsgBox "This cell is not accessible. Please use the designated input methods."
End If End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it but it does nothing.

Comment: Did you protect the sheet and let the user just select the non-protected cells?